# variable database name

Tags: sql, mysql

Is there any way in MySQL to put the name of the database into a variable?
For example, when I have a database called 'db1', can I do something like this:

```
set @db= 'db1';
select * from @db.mytable;
```

EDIT: There is another example of what I want to do:

```
set @dbfrom= 'db1';
set @dbto= 'db2';
insert into @dbto.mytable (col1,col2,col3) select col2,col1,col3 from @dbfrom.mytable;
```

Comment: Any particular programming language or environment?  The connection with the database is where this is specified.

Comment: it's just mysql.. I'll dump it to myadmin

Comment: Could you use a use statement http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/use.html?

Comment: I have select data from one db and insert it into another db..

Answer (score 32, accepted):

With considerable effort, yes.

```
SET @db = 'db1';
SET @q = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM ', @db, '.mycol');
PREPARE stmt FROM @q;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [Chaos' 'Prepare Statement' solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/701007/662581) I managed to create a Stored Procedure which uses a variable database name.

Works like a charm for migrating data from one database to another with a Stored Procedure. This way the code isn't pinned to a single database.

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `SampleProcedure` $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `SampleProcedure`(IN HubDatabaseName VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN

SET @db = HubDatabaseName;
SET @q = CONCAT('

/* Import data from Hub database to local database */
INSERT INTO `table_name_in_local_database`
SELECT
  *
FROM
  ', @db ,'.`tablename`

');

PREPARE stmt FROM @q;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have PHP installed you could use this script to replace the mysql variables to there actual value:

```
<?php

$sqlFile = 'migration.sql';
$fromDb = 'db1';
$toDb = 'db2';

echo str_replace(['@fromDb', '@toDb'], [$fromDb, $toDb], file_get_contents($sqlFile));
```