# How to move data between 2 tables / with different columns in different databases

Tags: mysql

We have the following scenario where `foo` has been renamed as `foo1`.

`foo.col1` has been renamed as `foo1.col11`.

`foo.col2` has been removed

In fact these used to be similar tables and I would like to copy data from A to B for these tables. How would I go about doing a simple migration given that the table/column names have undergone a change.

```
Database 'A'
create table foo {id pk, col1 varchar(255), col2 tinyint(1), col3 datetime);
create table foo_bar1 (id pk, foo_id fk, col4 datetime, col5 varchar(255));

Database 'B'
create table foo1 {id pk, col11 varchar(255), col3 datetime);
create table foo1_bar1 (id pk, foo1_id fk, col4 datetime, col5 varchar(255));
```

Comment: INSERT INTO B.foo (id, col11, col3) SELECT id, col1, col3 FROM A.foo

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you should be able to do:

```
INSERT INTO B.foo1 (id, col11, col3) 
 SELECT id,col1,col3 FROM A.foo;

INSERT INTO B.foo1_bar1 (id, foo1_id, col4, col5) 
 SELECT id,foo_id,col4,col5 FROM A.foo_bar1;
```

Comment: Is there a way to pass the database names as arguments to the sql script which will be executed on database 'B'

Comment: if you look at the sql statements above you can see that the database name is already included, you don't need to select a database in your sql script. eg. insert into <databasename>.<tablename> ... works even if you have not selected "<databasename>" before

Comment: No, is there a way to pass the source database as an argument (e.g. for 'A')

Comment: @priya: you could dynamically generate the statements in a language of your choice (php, ruby, Perl, Java...), or using MySQL's `PREPARE FROM`.

Comment: passing the target database  as argument would have been easy, but I'm not aware of a mysql feature that has general placeholder substitution in sql script files. you could do some sed replace magic to generate your script, but maybe someone else knows a better solution

Comment: Thanks Gryphius, but for portability purposes I would still prefer to pass the argument from the command prompt rather than hardcoding in the script itself.

Comment: just found a possible way.. I added it as a new answer, it's a bit too long for a comment

Answer (score 1):

```
BEGIN;
INSERT INTO B.foo1 (id, col11, col3) 
   SELECT id, col1, col3 
   FROM A.foo;
INSERT INTO B.foo1_bar1 (id, foo1_id, col4, col5) 
   SELECT id, foo_id, col4, col5 
   FROM A.foo_bar1;
COMMIT;
```

Answer (score 1):

IF you know the columns that have been removed you can do a straight insert of query results:

```
INSERT INTO B.foo1 (id, col11, col3) (SELECT id, col1, col3 FROM A.foo);
INSERT INTO B.foo_bar1 (id, foo1_id, col4, col5) (SELECT id, foo_id, col4, col5 FROM A.foo_bar1);
```

Answer (score 1):

another solution that includes your 2nd question to set the source database name dynamically

create your script 'bla.sql':

```
SET @q = CONCAT('INSERT INTO B.foo1 (id, col11, col3) 
  SELECT id,col1,col3 FROM ',@sourcedb,'.foo');
PREPARE stmt FROM @q;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

(add additional statements as needed)

then run from console:

```
mysql -e "SET @sourcedb:='A' ; source bla.sql;" B -u root
```

source for this solution:
[variable database name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/700970/variable-database-name)
and koneraks comment ;-)