# MySQL/PhpMyAdmin copy table with different columns

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Wondering if someone can kindly help. I am sure I have done this before but I can't remember how!

I have two tables

database.users - old
database.site_users - new

Both have matching columns but the OLD table has more custom columns that aren't used anymore.

Can I copy the users from the old database to the new database, but ensuring it only copies the data from columns that still exist?

At the moment I get a load of errors about the column count doesn't match etc.

Thank you to anyone who can help :)

Comment: Maybe you can try this also: `INSERT INTO newdatabase.table SELECT col1  AS newtablecol1name,  col2  as newtablecol2name ... FROM olddatabase.tablename`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have just commented, but I can't yet.

To do this I think you would either need to:
1. Make sure you have the same columns on both tables, perform the transfer and then delete the unneeded columns on the new table.
2. Write a script or query that Selects all the data from the old table and inserts it into the new table in the required format.
3. Export the data, make the required changed to the file and then re-import it (this would be tedious).

EDIT: This seems to have been answered here [How to move data between 2 tables / with different columns in different databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7964810/how-to-move-data-between-2-tables-with-different-columns-in-different-database)

Using:

```
INSERT INTO B.foo1 (id, col11, col3) 
 SELECT id,col1,col3 FROM A.foo;
```