# mysql use variable to store database name in sql script

Tags: mysql, variables

I have a sql file I will use for adding new records into a database. it involves much re-formatting data as the target is normalised to a far greater extent than the source. can I declare table names initially like

```
srcdb = 'dump_130113';
targetdb = 'test';
```

then refer to them like

```
select * from srcdb.tablename;
```

I know about

```
use database_name;
```

the problem is even doing that will require switching back and forth many times.

Comment: Can you wrap what you're doing in a scripting language like PHP or Perl? They can substitute into the SQL commands.

Comment: Check [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/700970/variable-database-name).

Comment: Looks like too much effort tbh, thanks anyway :)

Comment: Have you seen the answer provided at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/700970/variable-database-name