# Database name as variable

Tags: sql-server

I have a database with stored procedures which selects data from another database

```
select * from Users in AnotherDatabase.dbo.Users
```

I have a couple of versions of the other database, i.e.

```
AnotherDatabaseProduction, AnotherDatabaseDevelopment, AnotherDatabaseStage
```

I remember a while back that I created some kind of global variable like `AnotherDatabase_Pointer` which I could set by running some stored procedure like `SetAnotherDatabaseToStage`:

```
AnotherDatabase_Pointer = 'AnotherDatabaseStage' //pseudo-code
```

Which I could then use in my stored procedures.

But I cannot seem to remember how it was done. All I can find is how to do this with string replacing/concatenating: [variable database name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/700970/variable-database-name) :(

Is this possible? MS SQL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are probably thinking of a [Synonym](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177544.aspx).

```
CREATE SYNONYM dbo.whatever FOR dbname.dbo.procedure_name;
```

Now, if you want to change it to some other database, you just drop and re-create the synonym:

```
DROP SYNONYM dbo.whatever;
GO
CREATE SYNONYM dbo.whatever FOR other_dbname.dbo.procedure_name;
```

Comment: +1, but I don't think this is necessarily any better than the dynamic SQL solution and if you wanted it to drop and create the synonym on the fly from a variable you'd still need to use dynamic SQL to build the synonym. I think the short answer (in my opinion) is that if the dynamic SQL solution won't work then you can't use a variable to specify a database.

Comment: @Love2Learn the point is that the stored procedure code can remain identical in all three databases, and only the synonym differs. That is far more powerful (and safe!) than using dynamic SQL. It also doesn't sound like they want to be changing this constantly on the fly (but maybe I'm not reading it right).

Comment: I know what you're saying and I don't disagree with the logic from an architecture perspective, but I think what the OP is saying is that they have a stored procedure on one database and they want to be able to pass a variable with the name of a target database to the stored procedure and have it query data from same named tables on various databases based on the variable. (I also could be reading it wrong.)

Comment: @Love2Learn I read it differently. They seemed to want a global variable (and even called it that). Otherwise I don't know why they would need to run a separate stored procedure to set the global variable. I'd still say that the synonym is better - even if using dynamic SQL to drop and re-point the synonym when the global variable needs to change, this is much better and safer IMHO than requiring the actual stored procedure to take that database name as a variable.

Comment: Yeah, upon re-reading I think you're right. I think the dynamic SQL to create the synonym would be where the OP has `'AnotherDatabaseProduction' //pseudo-code`. I think I got lost on the semantics of whether the target database's object was a table or a stored procedure. I still think it's a remote table referenced within a local stored procedure, but your point remains correct.

Comment: to clarify, @AaronBertrand read it they way I intended it. I tried to clarify the question a bit. So, we are not interested in sending the database name as a parameter to the stored procedure but instead changing the synonym while going between development, testing, staging. i.e. not too often.