# MySQL database name as alias for query between multiple databases

Tags: php, mysql, database

```
mysqli_query("SELECT login.validto,
(SELECT databases.databasename FROM DB1.databases WHERE databases.ID = login.ID ORDER BY databases.lastused DESC LIMIT 1) AS dbname, 
(SELECT users.username FROM dbname.users WHERE users.ID = '2') AS username
FROM DB1.login 
WHERE login.token = 'abc13def456';");
```

Is it possible to use the alias **dbname** as database for the subquery instead of using 2 separate queries from PHP?

Im using 1 database to handle all the logins and then we use X databases to hold all the customers data, one database for each customer and later on it should be possible for the customers to change between the databases.

Im curently getting error:

```
Error Code: 1142
SELECT command denied to user 'myMySQLuser'@'myMySQLhost' for table 'users'
```

Changing the **dbname** to the real database name works just fine and the **dbname** and real database is the same, but i want to make 1 query instead of 2 from my PHP script.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [variable database name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/700970/variable-database-name)

Comment: a little bit maby, but i wanna use 1 single select and not run multiple queries with **SET** before i can use the variable/alias.

Comment: I understand you. I suggest you to use [prepared statements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html). I think, you can use it inline without temporary variables.

Comment: @Alexander , i think i should have added that i use PHP, not sure prepare works sins i dont know the **dbname** until the first subquery sets the alias.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use the [existing solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/700970/variable-database-name) to create a [procedure](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-procedure.html) on MySQL server that will be called from your PHP appliation.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE my_proc()
BEGIN
  DECLARE @dbname, @username VARCHAR(25);
  # Set @dbname value
  SELECT databases.databasename INTO @dbname FROM DB1.databases WHERE databases.ID = login.ID ORDER BY databases.lastused DESC LIMIT 1;
  # Create query to set @username value from required database
  SET @user_query = CONCAT('SELECT users.username INTO @username FROM ', @dbname, '.users WHERE users.ID =2;');
  PREPARE stmt FROM @user_query;
  EXECUTE stmt; # set @username value
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
  # Main query
  SELECT validto, @dbname, @username 
  FROM FROM DB1.login WHERE login.token = 'abc13def456';
END
```

Also you can call the procedure with parameters that you need. Then you will be able to use simple PHP statement to get required data.

Comment: yes, but doesnt that require me to know what database to use ?, i dont know what database it is until part of the query fetch that information, and with user input it can change.

Comment: @user1271152 , use separate query to get required database name, then use that name to prepare a new query. In my example I use 3 queries, but it is possible to be reduced.